# Unable to execute the sample tests in webdriverio after setting it up as per the offecial guide

Tags: webdriver-io

question:

I have installed Webdriverio and set it up as per the official document but it throws an error when try to execute it in command line. Getting below error.

result:
equestError: RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND googlechromelabs.github.io
at ClientRequest. (file:///C:/Sample%20project/wdio2/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:792:107)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:35)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:108:26)

Comment: Hello , Please provide more info like package.json, what command you run when you get this error ?  Try posting some snapshots that help the community to solve your problem

Comment: hi, Thanks for the response, please find the below details.      package -  {
  "name": "my-new-project",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.16.12",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.16.12",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.16.12",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.16.12",
     "chromedriver": "^91.0.1",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js"
  }
}     have used "npx wdio run wdio.conf.js" and "npm run wdio" to execute but getting the same issue.

Comment: One hint is, while installingwdio, there was no option to select chromedriver service , i have manully installed it using 'npm install wdio-chromedriver-service --save-dev' but still it didnt work for me. Can some help me on this.

Comment: Are you sure that is not a proxy issue?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps below, forget everything that you have done so far.

1. Create New Folder
2. On that Particular folder or directory Run these commands one by one & your problem must get resolved.

   npm init

   npm init wdio

   npm install

Keep Learning !! Keep Growing !! Let me know if you still face any Issue

Comment: Hi, I had tried this before also and again i have tried now, still am getting the same error.   
? A project named "wdio1" was detected at "C:\Sample project\wdio1", correct? Yes
? What type of testing would you like to do? E2E Testing - of Web or Mobile Applications
? Where is your automation backend located? On my local machine
? Which environment you would like to automate? Web - web applications in the browser
? With which browser should we start? Chrome
? Which framework do you want to use? Mocha (https://mochajs.org/)
? Do you want to use a compiler? No!

Comment: ? Do you want WebdriverIO to autogenerate some test files? Yes
? Where should these files be located? C:\Sample project\wdio1\test\specs\**\*.js
? Do you want to use page objects (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html)? Yes
? Where are your page objects located? C:\Sample project\wdio1\test\pageobjects\**\*.js
? Which reporter do you want to use? spec
? Do you want to add a plugin to your test setup?
? Do you want to add a service to your test setup?
? What is the base url? http://localhost
? Do you want me to run `npm install` Yes

Comment: I have observed one this is in the latest webdriver there is no chromedriver service entry, i have tried to install that  manually  by using   -> npm install wdio-chromedriver-service --save-dev  but still it is failing with the same error. This is the devDepencies after installing the chromedriverservice manually     "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.16.15",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.16.15",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.16.15",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.16.12",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1" }   "Am trying this in my ofc laptop, is this issue becs of that.

Comment: Any help on this please?

Comment: Hello

1 please uninstall & try again
2 check your chrome browser version on your pc . It must be latest .

Comment: i have tried that many times and still not working. My chrome version is 117.0.5938.132. Do you think is there any other issues ?